# Parentheses in JQ for .key

Tags: json, jq

I don't understand why key has to be in `()` for this to work:

```
# kbrandt at glade.local in ~ on git:master x [15:08:19]
$ cat host | jq '. | to_entries | map({ (.key) : .value.CPU.PercentUsed })' | tail
  {
    "rpi-b827eb2d7d23": 10.333333333333334
  },
  {
    "rpi-b827eb8d7c8d": 60
  },
  {
    "rpi-b827eba999fa": 40.733333333333334
  }
]

# kbrandt at glade.local in ~ on git:master x [15:08:54]
$ cat host | jq '. | to_entries | map({ .key : .value.CPU.PercentUsed })' | tail
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
. | to_entries | map({ .key : .value.CPU.PercentUsed })
jq: 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When defining an object literal, the parentheses indicates that the expression value should be the property name.  Otherwise if you didn't use parentheses, it's the literal name.

So these are equivalent ways to define an object with a `"foo"` property:

```
{ foo: 1 }
{ "foo": 2 }
"foo" as $name | { ($name): 3 }
{ somename: "foo" } | { (.somename): 4 }
```

Comment: So how come `.value.CPU.PercentUsed` doesn't need to be in parentheses?

Comment: It's the value for that property.  It's only required for the key if you want to give a name by value.  You don't necessarily need to put the value in parentheses.