# Construct JSON with a variable key using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use `jq` to construct a hash in which a key name comes from a variable. Something like this:

```
jq --null-input --arg key foobar '{$key: "value"}'
```

This doesn't work, however, and gives the following error:

```
error: syntax error, unexpected '$'
{$key: "value"} 1 compile error
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use parentheses to evaluate `$key` early as in:

```
 jq --null-input --arg key foobar '{($key): "value"}'
```

See also: [Parentheses in JQ for .key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700997/parentheses-in-jq-for-key)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)) in `jq` which is of the form `"\(..)"`. Inside the string, you can put an expression inside parens after a backslash. Whatever the expression returns will be interpolated into the string.

You can do below. The contents of the variable `key` is expanded and returned as a string by the interpolation sequence.

```
jq --null-input --arg key foobar '{ "\($key)": "value"}'
```