# Adding values to dynamic keys with jq

Tags: json, jq

I try to construct a json object with jq. I start with an empty object and want to add keys and values dynamically.

This works but the key is not variable. It's fixed to "foo":

```
echo '{"foo": ["baz"]}' | jq --arg value "bar" '.foo += [$value]'
```

output as expected:

```
{"foo": ["baz", "bar"]}
```

What I actually want do do is something like this:

```
echo '{"foo": ["baz"]}' | jq --arg key "foo" --arg value "bar" '.($key) += [$value]'
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Here is the output:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

.($key) += [$value]

jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:

.($key) += [$value]

jq: 2 compile errors
```

I couldn't find a solution or figure it out.

I know that this works: `jq --null-input --arg key foo '{($key): "bar"}'` but it doesn't solve my problem since I want to append values to existing lists as you can see in the examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use square parens `[..]` instead of `(..)` as reported in the error message. Just do

```
jq --arg key "foo" --arg value "bar" '.[$key] += [$value]'
```

This error line is quite verbose to recommend you the right syntax to use. The emphasis with `#` is mine

```
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1
#              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank, it works. I actually tried this but I was mislead since it said replace `.field ` by `.["field"]`. I used `.["($key)"]` which of course does not work.

Comment: I learned that for usually named fields `()` is used and for unusual fields your solution with []

Comment: for nested dynamic keys use `.a.b[$c]` or `.a.b["c"]` or `.a.b."c"`. alternative: [Construct JSON with a variable key using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841309/construct-json-with-a-variable-key-using-jq)