# How to dynamically use github secrets in a github action, according to list of secret names provided?

Tags: github-actions

What i'm trying to achieve, is eventually to dispatch an action, with list of comma separated secret names.

What i want to do is to loop over the names and use the secrets, from this example - just print them.

I have 2 secrets SEC_1 and SEC_2 in my repo.

```
jobs:
  dev:
    name: dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    env:
      ENVIRONMENT: DEV
    steps:
      - run: |
          # Define the secrets
          secrets="SEC_1,SEC_2"

          # Split the secrets string into an array
          IFS=',' read -ra secret_array <<< "$secrets"

          # Loop over the secret names and echo their values
          for secret_name in "${secret_array[@]}"; do
            echo ${{ format('{0}', '$secret_name') }}

            # This prints nothing!
            echo ${{ secrets[format('{0}', '$secret_name')] }} | sed 's/./& /g'
          done

        # This works perfectly
        echo ${{ secrets[format('{0}', 'SEC_1')] }} | sed 's/./& /g'
        echo ${{ secrets[format('{0}', 'SEC_2')] }} | sed 's/./& /g'
```

i've tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255989/dynamically-retrieve-github-actions-secret) - but nothing works as i don't have fixed number of variables i can define as env vars

What am i missing?

---

As per the comment, managed to do it, thanks @Azeem!

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      my_secrets:
        description: "list of secrets to fetch"
        required: true

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  dev:
    name: dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    env:
      SECRETS: '${{ toJson(secrets) }}'
    steps:
      - run: |
          IFS=',' read -ra string_array <<< ${{ github.event.inputs.my_secrets }}

          for secret in "${string_array[@]}"; do
            value="$(jq -r --arg key "$secret" '.[$key]' <<< "$SECRETS" | sed 's|.|& |g')"
            echo "$secret: $value"
          done
```

Comment: You can convert `secrets` context to JSON with `toJSON` and then use `jq` to query your dynamic secrets. Here's an [example](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJxNjjFvwjAQhXf/iqfIqmEwUju66YRYOpZuVYWMc5CQYFPbASHCf29IrLTL3endd++d1UdSKK5WHyuzCWQ8xcCYswoX5+td4y6bogonHU3J2MFtg2KAqR4V8K0N8sG229bGVjY6Uohs2IVIpzBiEnaIWZZk6kEByJ5VGoH1avmx+lwrCH67Ibr34OwsPTPH/S4S2ecpdNPZznmMFCqbTJ5Tf3lF4SYSOOumpbeMzw4/kB5Sar9HTVdkfLTIIBZfvFe+BfI87/X0VYauTykgQrfontDtxTz7Z0ymdJOJAh+C/oDCWWK/2Opj+Q==).

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850797/adding-values-to-dynamic-keys-with-jq

Comment: @Azeem yes! that was it!
can you add it as an answer? i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `secrets` context to JSON with `toJSON` function and then use `jq` to query your dynamic secrets.

Here's an example:

```yaml
name: dynamic_secrets

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check
      env:
        SECRETS: '${{ toJson(secrets) }}'
      run: |
        for secret in SECRET1 SECRET2; do
          value="$(jq -r --arg key "$secret" '.[$key]' <<< "$SECRETS" | sed 's|.|& |g')"
          echo "$secret: $value"
        done
```

Output:

[image: screenshot]

---

References:

- [`toJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson)
- [Adding values to dynamic keys with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850797/adding-values-to-dynamic-keys-with-jq)