# jq how to pass json keys from a shell variable

Tags: json, shell, parsing, jq

I have a json file I am parsing with `jq`. This is a sample of the file

```
[{
"key1":{...},
"key2":{...}
}]
[{
"key1":{...},
"key2":{...}
}]
...
```

each line is a list containing a json (which I know is not technically a `json` format but `jq` still works on such a file)

The below `jq` command works:

```
cat file.json | jq -r '.[] | [.key1,.key2]'
```

The above correctly shows:

```
[
<value_of_key1>,<value_of_key2>
]
[
<value_of_key1>,<value_of_key2>
]
```

However, I want `.key1,.key2` to be dynamic since these keys can change. So I want to pass a variable to `jq`. Something like:

```
$KEYS=.key1,.key2
cat file.json | jq -r --arg var "$KEYS" '.[] | [$var]'
```

But the above is returning the keys themselves:

```
[
".key1,.key2"
]
[
".key1,.key2"
]
```

why is this happening? what is the correct command to make this happen?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841309/construct-json-with-a-variable-key-using-jq) does not help me. I am not getting any errors as the OP in that question.

Comment: Use bracket notation

Comment: @0stone0 this does not work. already seen it.

Comment: Just now seeing that you're trying to parse multiple keys with just 1 arg, Is that intended?

Comment: @0stone0 because as you can see the argument itself is multiple keys. `$KEYS=.key1,.key2`. I suggest you read carefully before closing a potentially helpful question.

Comment: yes it is as intended. `$KEYS=.key1,.key2`. Already outlined this above ^ 5 min ago

Comment: Oke, I was just confirming. But since you can't take a question without sounding irritated, I wish you the best of luck finding an answer.

Comment: I'm absolutely not irritated. It was not my intention to sound like that if that is the case. I'm sorry that your wrongly interpreted emotional analysis from text will make you not share your knowledge with whoever stumbles on this question. (again not irritated).

Comment: Not irritated, but just insulting regardless being in an even-keeled emotional state? As an outside observer, I don't see how that's any better.

Comment: Anyhow -- this is a case where what you claim you want is best implemented with `jq -r ".[] | [$keys]"` -- note double quotes instead of single quotes, so the shell is generating code for jq to execute. That's usually undesirable, but this is a special case.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, ouch. Building code from the shell... That never goes wrong.

Comment: @ikegami, ...sure, but the OP _wants_ the effect of `eval`; hence, it's expected for them to get its pitfalls.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, No, they want to select keys. The extent of what they need exactly is unclear, but saying they want/need `eval` is not a reasonable assumption

Comment: @ikegami I updated the question showing the correct output.

Comment: You didn't change it, but the error was mine. Sorry, comment deleted.

Comment: Tip: The `-r` makes no sense and ends up being ignored as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetching the value of a jq variable doesn't cause it to be executed as jq code.

Furthermore, jq lacks the facility to take a string, compile it as jq code, and evaluate the result. (This is commonly known as `eval`.)

So, short of a writing a jq parser and evaluator in jq, you will need to impose limits and/or accept a different format.

For example,

```sh
keys='[ [ "key1", "childkey" ], [ "key2", "childkey2" ] ]'  # JSON
jq --argjson keys "$keys" '.[] | [ getpath( $keys[] ) ]' file.json
```

or

```sh
keys='key1.childkey,key2.childkey2'
jq --arg keys "$keys" '
   ( ( $keys / "," ) | map( . / "." ) ) as $keys |
   .[] | [ getpath( $keys[] ) ]
' file.json
```

Comment: Also, if needed, the value for the `keys` variable could be generated by using another invocation of jq. In the first example (JSON array) for instance like so: `keys="$(echo key1 key2 | jq -Rnc 'inputs/" "')"`.

Comment: @pmf, Maybe? The example is a bad one. You'd just use the second approach with a space instead of a comma rather than a second invocation of `jq`. And I can't think of case where it would make sense.

Comment: My use-case in mind was having a text file or another program's output providing the keys, which when fed into jq could produce a valid JSON to be then used as input. But never mind, it was just a suggestion...

Comment: @pmf, You could use `--arg keys "$( cat file )"`

Comment: @ikegami your first example is almost correct. I am getting `[null,null]` as output. and I know the keys I am using are correct because I tested just in case. Your second example I cannot get it to work

Comment: @bcsta The first works fine. The second was missing parens. [Demo](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/93f421f94e8c080d1c7565f08e892010)

Comment: @ikegami you are right the first one works for a flat json. what if I have nested keys. I was doing `keys='key1.childkey,key2.childkey2'` which is why i was getting `[null,null]`. Do you have any suggestions for nested keys?

Comment: The answer already suggested you could use `getpath` to do that. Updated examples.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have:

```
cat file
[{
"key1":1,
"key2":2
}]
[{
"key1":1,
"key2":2
}]
```

You can use a `jq` command like so:

```
jq '.[] | [.key1,.key2]' file
[
  1,
  2
]
[
  1,
  2
]
```

You can use `-f` to execute a filter from a file and nothing keeps you from creating the file separately from the shell variables.

Example:

```
keys=".key1"
echo ".[] | [${keys}]" >jqf

jq -f jqf file
[
  1
]
[
  1
]
```

Or just build the string directly into `jq`:

```
# note double " causing string interpolation
jq ".[] | [${keys}]" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--argjson` option and `destructuring`.

file.json

```
[{"key1":{"a":1},"key2":{"b":2}}]
[{"key1":{"c":1},"key2":{"d":2}}]
```

```
$ in='["key1","key2"]' jq -c --argjson keys "$in" '$keys as [$key1,$key2] | .[] | [.[$key1,$key2]]' file.json
```

output:

```
[{"a":1},{"b":2}]
[{"c":1},{"d":2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on ikegami's answer.

To start with here's my version of the answer:

```
$ in='key1.a,key2.b'; jq -c --arg keys "$in" '($keys/","|map(./".")) as $paths | .[] | [getpath($paths[])]' <<<$'[{"key1":{"a":1},"key2":{"b":2}}] [{"key1":{"a":3},"key2":{"b":4}}]'
```

This gives output

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```

Let's try it.

We have input

```
[{"key1":{"a":1},"key2":{"b":2}}]
[{"key1":{"a":3},"key2":{"b":4}}]
```

And we want to construct array

```
[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]
```

then use it on `getpath(PATHS)` builtin to extract values out of our input.

To start with we are given `in` *shell variable* with string value `key1.a,key2.b`. Let's call this `$keys`.

Then `$keys/","` gives

```
["key1.a","key2.b"]
["key1.a","key2.b"]
```

After that `$keys/","|map(./".")` gives what we want.

```
[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]
[["key1","a"],["key2","b"]]
```

Let's call this `$paths`.

Now if we do `.[]|[getpath($paths[])]` we get the values from our `input` equivalent to

```
[.[] | .key1.a, .key2.b]
```

which is

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
```