# JQ Create JSON Key and Value Pair

Tags: json, object, syntax, key, jq

I'm trying to create a JSON file with this very simple command:

`jq -n --arg greeting world --arg mykey hello '{"hello":$greeting}'`

My problem is that when I replace the key with $mykey I get this error:

```
# jq -n --arg greeting world --arg mykey hello {$mykey:$greeting}
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{:}
jq: 1 compile error
```

How can I create a simple JSON file with two arguments/variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parentheses in JQ for .key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700997/parentheses-in-jq-for-key)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), when a key name is specified programmatically, the defining expression must be enclosed in parentheses:

```
$ jq -n --arg greeting world --arg mykey hello '{($mykey):$greeting}'
{
  "hello": "world"
}
```